# Problems to print at windows 7 (windows XP is ok) for Zebra TLP 2844

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, zebra-printers

I have a web application (c# framework 3.5) to send labels to print and two zebras `tlp 2844` (first one is installed at windows XP and another one is installed at windows 7 - both are shared).

Using the same application and code I can print in Zebra at Windows XP (I just change de path: `192.168.0.251/ZebraTest`). I cannot print at Zebra on Windows 7 (path: `192.168.0.121/ZebraTest`).

I have already change the printers, installed using the last drivers and the problem is the same - and I can print only at Windows XP.

The error is: Invalid handle - returns -1 at the port.
Follow the code (the error occurs this line: `zPrint.StartWrite(impressora);`):

```
Waterfurnace.ZebraPrint zPrint = new Waterfurnace.ZebraPrint();
zPrint.StartWrite(impressora);
zPrint.Write("Q508,019");
zPrint.Write("q831");
zPrint.Write("I8,A,351");
zPrint.Write("rN");
zPrint.Write("S3");
zPrint.Write("D7");
zPrint.Write("ZT");
zPrint.Write("JB");
zPrint.Write("OD");
zPrint.Write("R0,0");
zPrint.Write("N");
zPrint.Write("A815,415,2,3,4,3,N,\"" + nomecracha.ToUpper() + "\"");
zPrint.EndWrite();
```

I have already tried using another code like:

```
ZebraPrint zPrint = new ZebraPrint();
zPrint.StartWrite(impressora);
```

...

```
public void StartWrite(string printerPath)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SA = default(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    IntPtr hPortP = default(IntPtr);

    //Dim retval As Integer
    //Create connection
    _hPort = CreateFile(printerPath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, ref
     SA, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    //_hPort = CreateFile(printerPath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
    null, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    //Get unsafe pointer
    hPortP = new IntPtr(_hPort);

    //convert Integer to IntPtr 
    //Create file stream
    _outFile = new FileStream(hPortP, FileAccess.Write);

    //Create stream writer
    _fileWriter = new StreamWriter(_outFile, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
}

public void Write(string rawLine)
{
    _fileWriter.WriteLine(rawLine);
}

/// <summary>
/// This function must be called after writing to the zebra printer.
/// </summary>
public void EndWrite()
{
    //Clean up
    _fileWriter.Flush();
    _fileWriter.Close();
    _outFile.Close();
    CloseHandle(_hPort);
}
```